# template tag called in if statement

Tags: django, django-templates

I am wondering if there is any way that I can call a template tag from within an `if` statement.

I am trying to do the following.

```
{% for k,v in form.amenities.field.choices %}
    {% if {% check_hidden k %} %}
        {{ v }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `{% check_hidden k %}` tag returns `True` or `False` from the table for the item being looked up.
I can confirm that `{% check_hidden k %}` returns either `True` or `False` on it's own, but I am wondering if I can wrap an `if` statement around it?

The app that I am working with is inherited, so I am trying to minimize the amount of changes needing to be done for now. Currently it is just being rendered as `{{form.amenities}}`, but I have added an additional field to the model that I now need to check before displaying the field in the template.

If there is another way that this could be done, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does `check_hidden` work?  What does it depend on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like `check_hidden` was written as a template tag when what is needed is a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

```
{% if k|check_hidden_filter %}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was needing to do. I changed the tag to a filter and used `{% if k|check_hidden_filter %}` to call it and it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is that `check_hidden` does for a choice value needs to be fixed in a fundamental way.

If the field choices are dynamic, the correct set of choices needs to be established in the view function, removing the need to do check_hidden in the template at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+dynamic+choices

Will give you lots of ways to have dynamic choices.  Many of these are done in the view function, removing the need for this kind of if-statement in the template.

Comment: The choices aren't dynamic at this point. And yes, I agree that the work should be done in a view. I just don't want to get into it too deeply now as they are looking at possibly rebuilding the site anyway. This is more of a temp fix. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @bmeyer71: If they're not dynamic, then (1) delete the unused ones and (2) get rid of if if nonsense totally.

Comment: The reason is that some items need to be available briefly while a search is done, then removed from general use (hidden). But still allow those searches to continue to work. As I said, this is temporary and using the filter method solves the problem just fine for now.

Comment: @bmeyer71: "some items need to be available briefly while a search is done, then removed from general use (hidden)"  You also said, "The choices aren't dynamic".  Please chose one answer or the other answer.  I don't understand how it can be both.  Please explain.

Comment: The choices are always going to be available, they just aren't always visible. This way a search can be created by selecting the item, copy the url created by the search, then hide the item. This way the url can be used wherever they want, and the search will still work.